# 2D memory allocation using structure

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory

// I have to create a new imgr_t with initial size rows, cols and their reserved counterpart (rows and reserved_rows will be the same, as well as cols and reserved_cols to be the same). If allocation is successful (i.e. memory allocation succeeds), returns a pointer to a newly-allocated imgr_t, if unsuccessful, returns a null pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Structure type that encapsulates image: 2D array.
 * the rows represent the indices of the main array,
 * the cols represent the indices of the arrays pointed to by the pointers 
 * in the elements of the main array.
*/

typedef struct { 
    uint8_t** pixels;
    unsigned int rows;
    unsigned int cols;
    unsigned int reserved_rows;
    unsigned int reserved_cols;
} imgr_t;

/***** I am thinking something is wrong here but I cannot figure out what *****/

imgr_t* imgr_create(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols){

    imgr_t* arr;
    arr->rows = rows;
    arr->cols = cols;
    arr->reserved_rows = rows;
    arr->reserved_cols = cols;
    arr = malloc(rows*sizeof(imgr_t));
    for(int i = 0; i<arr->rows; i++){
        arr->pixels[i] = malloc(cols*sizeof(imgr_t));
    }return arr;
}

void imgr_destroy(imgr_t* im){
    if(im != NULL){
        free(im->pixels);
        free(im);
    }
}

// helper function that prints the content of the img
void print_img(imgr_t* im) {
    if (im == NULL) {
        printf("Invalid img (null).\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Printing img of row length %d and col length %d:\n", im->rows, im->cols);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<im->rows; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<im->cols; j++) {
            printf("%d ", im->pixels[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){

  imgr_t* test_im;
  printf("Creating test_im by calling 'img_create(10, 10)'\n");
  test_im = imgr_create(10, 10);
  printf("test_im created successfully.\n\n");

    
  return 0;
}

/*
    Output what I am getting : Creating test_im by calling 'img_create(10, 10)'
             signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)
*/
```

Comment: `imgr_t* arr;
    arr->rows = rows;
    arr->cols = cols;` have you learned about `malloc`? You need to allocate the memory used for this array (and `free` it later on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is that need the same number of call to `free` than ons to `malloc`.
And `uint8_t** pixels;` is not a pointer to a 2D array, but a pointer to pointers to array, so you need a two-pass allocation (and same at `free` time).

Here you need:

- 1 allocation for the `imgr_t` struct
- 1 allocation for the array of pointer to rows
- 1 allocation per row (*)

Code could be:

```
imgr_t* imgr_create(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols) {

    imgr_t* arr = malloc(sizeof *arr);
    if (NULL == arr) return arr;       // do not forget to test allocation!
    arr->rows = rows;
    arr->cols = cols;
    arr->reserved_rows = rows;
    arr->reserved_cols = cols;
    arr->pixels = malloc(rows * sizeof(*arr->pixels));  // allocate rows
    if (NULL == arr->pixels) {         // another allocation to test
        free(arr);
        return NULL;
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < arr->rows; i++) {
        arr->pixels[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(uint8_t));
        if (NULL == arr->pixels[i]) { // free what was allocated so far
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                free(arr->pixels[i]);
            }
            free(arr->pixels)
            free(arr);
            return NULL;

        }
    }return arr;
}

void imgr_destroy(imgr_t* im) {
    if (im != NULL) {
        // one free per malloc...
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < im->rows; i++) {
            free(im->pixels[i]);
        }
        free(im->pixels);
        free(im);
    }
}
```

BEWARE: I could not understand what *reserved* meant so I just ignore it...

---

(*) In fact it is possible to allocate the whole array in one pass and then have the pointer to rows point to the begin of each row in the global array, but it is an advanced way...

Comment: Reserved rows and reserved cols are, for example, currently, the rows and reserved_rows are 10 and cols and reserved_cols are 10. If the user appends a value such that the number of rows should increase, then you increase rows to 11 and double the size of reserved_rows to 20 along with the number of rows allocated in memory for your 2D array. Since I am not appending anything yet I'm guessing they don't have much to do here, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
imgr_t* imgr_create(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols){

    imgr_t* arr;
    arr->rows = rows;
    arr->cols = cols;
    arr->reserved_rows = rows;
    arr->reserved_cols = cols;
    arr = malloc(rows*sizeof(imgr_t));
    for(int i = 0; i<arr->rows; i++){
        arr->pixels[i] = malloc(cols*sizeof(imgr_t));
    }return arr;
}
```

Here you use `arr` before its initialization. And your initialization seems wrong because you simply need to allocate 1 `imgr_t` element. The pixels initialization also seems wrong to me: the type is incorrect, you need to use the type `uint8_t`. You also need to allocate some space to store your pixels:

```
imgr_t* imgr_create(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols){

  imgr_t* arr = malloc(sizeof(imgr_t));
  arr->rows = rows;
  arr->cols = cols;
  arr->reserved_rows = rows;
  arr->reserved_cols = cols;
  arr->pixels = malloc(rows * sizeof(uint8_t*));

  for(int i = 0; i<arr->rows; i++){
    arr->pixels[i] = malloc(cols*sizeof(uint8_t));
  }

  return arr;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping out, but I still can't figure it out, I tried implementing what you just said but im still getting the same result

Comment: imgr_t* imgr_create(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols){
        imgr_t* arr = malloc(sizeof(imgr_t));
    if(arr != NULL){

      arr->rows = rows;
      arr->cols = cols;
      arr->reserved_rows = rows;
      arr->reserved_cols = cols; 

      for(int i = 0; i<arr->rows; i++){
        arr->pixels[i] = malloc(cols*sizeof(imgr_t));
      }
      return arr;
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: The updated code is slightly better. But I would suggest you to learn how to use a debugger like `gdb`, it is very convenient. They will tell you which line of code have a problem, this is very handy to fix segmentation faults.